# can i extract different values from same text with using xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath

Can i extract 3 different values from below codes with using xpath

```
<div class="demo">Prize - 4 G - 14.15</div>
```

Planned conclusion must be told the following:

**1st:** Prize

**2nd:** 4G

**3td:** 14.15

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three XPaths would get the information out:

```
substring-before(//div,' - ')
substring-before(substring-after(//div,' - '),' - ')
substring-after(substring-after(//div,' - '),' - ')
```

But I'm not sure what you are using this for, so I'm not sure this is what you are really after.